# Mac Bash nested for loop path error , when dir has a spacing whihin

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I want to rename files ,turn

```
Root---A----0.png
|      |
|      ----1.png
|
-------B----0.png
       |
       ----1.png
```

to

```
Root---A----0_0.png
|      |
|      ----0_1.png
|
-------B----1_0.png
       |
       ----1_1.png
```

Here is my code, first part

```
Base=$(pwd)
for path in *
    do 
    if [[ -d $path ]]; then
        NewPath="${Base}/${path}"
        for f in $(ls $NewPath)
            do
            echo mv "$f" "A_$f"
        done 
    fi
done
```

**I encount a qestion, when A'name is `(4 )`, there is a spacing in it.**

Terminal reports:

> ls: ): No such file or directory ls: /Users/jzd/Pictures/try/try/(4:
>
> No such file or directory

---

**Firstly,**
tested in terminal, `ls /Users/jzd/Pictures/try/try/\(4\ \)` is OK,

I saw `/Users/jzd/Pictures/try/try/(4`, then I add escape character,

the inner loop:

```
if [[ -d $path ]]; then
        NewPath="${Base}/${path}"
        p=$(echo $NewPath | sed -e 's/[ ()]/\\&/g')
        for f in $(ls $p)
            do echo mv "$f" "A_$f"
        done 
    fi
```

Terminal reports:

> ls: /Users/jzd/Pictures/try/try/(3): No such file or directory  ls:
>
> /Users/jzd/Pictures/try/try/(4: No such file or directory  ls: ):
>
> No such file or directory

---

**secondly:**
I need to let `ls` treat path as a single String, so I add `IFS`

```
Base=$(pwd)
OLDIFS="$IFS"  # save it
IFS="" # don't split on any white space
for path in *
    do 
    if [[ -d $path ]]; then
        NewPath="${Base}/${path}"
        for f in $(ls $NewPath)
            do echo mv "$f" "A_$f"
        done 
    fi
done
IFS=$OLDIFS # restore IFS
```

Terminal reports:

> mv 0.png
>
> 1.png A_0.png
>
> 1.png mv 0.png
>
> 1.png A_0.png
>
> 1.png

Not I want.

Comment: Why are you using `ls` at all?

Comment: `find` is a good option. Use `ls` to record the dir number is easy.